Unable to retrieve login page using IdentityServer 7 for an MVC application
I am currently doing a course covering .NET and the MVC architecture.
When running the application, the home page for the Identity Server project loads as normal, however it does not load other views such as "Account/Login" even though they are in the appropriate folder structure within the Views folder. The page simply returns "This localhost page can't be found."
Here's Program.cs for the Identity Server project (containing the login page):
using Duende.IdentityServer.AspNetIdentity;
using Mango.Services.Identity.DbContexts;
using Mango.Services.Identity.Initializer;
using Mango.Services.Identity.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace Mango.Services.Identity
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            // Add services to the container.
            builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

            // Add database context and connect to the database.
            builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            var IDBuilder = builder.Services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
            {
                options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
                options.EmitStaticAudienceClaim = true;
            }).AddInMemoryIdentityResources(SD.IdentityResources)
            .AddInMemoryApiScopes(SD.ApiScopes)
            .AddInMemoryClients(SD.Clients)
            .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();

            builder.Services.AddScoped<IDbInitializer, DbInitializer>();

            IDBuilder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();

            var app = builder.Build();

            if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
                app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            // Create a scope to resolve the scoped service IDbInitializer.
            using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
            {
                var scopedServices = scope.ServiceProvider;
                var dbInitializer = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<IDbInitializer>();
                dbInitializer.Initialize();
            }

            app.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            app.Run();
        }
    }
}


Details containing the URIs:
using Duende.IdentityServer;
using Duende.IdentityServer.Models;

namespace Mango.Services.Identity
{
    public static class SD
    {
        public const string Admin = "Admin";
        public const string Customer = "Customer";

        public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> IdentityResources =>
            new List<IdentityResource>()
            {
                new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
                new IdentityResources.Email(),
                new IdentityResources.Profile()
            };

        public static IEnumerable<ApiScope> ApiScopes =>
            new List<ApiScope>() 
            {
                new ApiScope("mango", "Mango Server"),
                new ApiScope(name: "read", displayName: "Read your data"),
                new ApiScope(name: "write", displayName: "Write your data"),
                new ApiScope(name: "delete", displayName: "Delete your data")
            };
            
        public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients =>
            new List<Client>
            { 
                new Client
                {
                    ClientId="client",
                    ClientSecrets = { new Secret("secret".Sha256()) },
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
                    AllowedScopes={ "read", "write", "profile"}
                },

                new Client
                {
                    ClientId="mango",
                    ClientSecrets = { new Secret("secret".Sha256()) },
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
                    RedirectUris = { "https://localhost:44300/signin-oidc" },
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = {"https://localhost:44300/signout-callback-oidc"},
                    AllowedScopes= new List<string>
                    {
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                        "mango"
                    }
                }
            };
    }
}

Program.cs for the web project containing the home page:
using Mango.Web.Services;
using Mango.Web.Services.IServices;
using Mango.Web;

namespace MangoWeb
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
            ConfigureServices(builder.Services, builder.Configuration);
            var app = builder.Build();
            Configure(app, app.Environment);

            app.MapRazorPages();
            app.Run();
        }

        private static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            // Add services to the container
            services.AddHttpClient();
            SD.ProductAPIBase = configuration["ServiceUrls:ProductAPI"];
            services.AddScoped<IProductService, ProductService>();
            services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
            })
            .AddCookie("Cookies", c => c.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10))
            .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
            {
                options.Authority = configuration["ServiceUrls:IdentityAPI"];
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                options.ClientId = "mango";
                options.ClientSecret = "secret";
                options.ResponseType = "code";
                options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
                options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "role";
                options.Scope.Add("mango");
                options.SaveTokens = true;
            });
        }

        private static void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
}


Controller responsible for redirecting the user to the login page:
using MangoWeb.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace MangoWeb.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
        
        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }

        [Authorize]
        public IActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        } 


        public IActionResult Logout()
        {
            return SignOut("Cookies", "oidc");
        }
    }
}

I am probably missing something very minor, and I've tried many different solutions to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.
